# explain the CSS selections with sign"~" for following example code?

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors

**what I have**
when I am going through [geek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css/) ended up with some doubts

```
<label class="script">
       Yes
       <input type="checkbox">
       <span class="geekmark"></span>
</label>
```

**some CSS selectors I don't understand**

```
1) .script:hover input~.geekmark {}
2) .script input:active~.geekmark{}
3) .script input:checked~.geekmark {}
4) .script input:checked~.geekmark:after{}
5) .script .geekmark:after{}
```

please explain them in descriptive way,
like if we have **parent:hover > child{} when mouse hovered over parent then the child get styled** please explain those above 5 CSS selections in such descriptive manner

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Sure, here's an explanation of each of the 5 CSS selectors:

1. **.script:hover input~.geekmark**- Selects the element with class
   .geekmark that is a sibling of the input element and only applies
   the styles when the parent element with
   class .script is hovered over.
2. **.script input:active~.geekmark** - Selects the element with class
   .geekmark that is a sibling of the input element and only applies
   the styles when the input element is actively being clicked.
3. **.script input:checked~.geekmark** - Selects the element with class
   .geekmark that is a sibling of the input element and only applies
   the styles when the input element is in a
   checked state.
4. **.script input:checked~.geekmark:after** - Selects the pseudo-element
   :after of the element with class .geekmark that is a sibling of the
   input element and only applies the styles when the input element is in a
   checked state.
5. **.script .geekmark:after** - Selects the pseudo-element :after of the
   element with class .geekmark that is a child of the element with
   class .script and applies the styles to it.

Comment: `` .script input:active~.geekmark `` , can you write alternative CSS selection for this.